# Visual Studio 2008 Preprocessor wierdness

Tags: visual-studio-2008, preprocessor

We have set-up a simple versioning system for our builds to ensure the built files always indicate whether they are Beta Debug or Beta Release builds

I moved the file version info to to myapp.rc2 and created version.h

```
    // version.h 
    // _DEBUG is defined by VS

    #define _BETA

    #ifdef _BETA
    #define FILE_DESC1   _T("BETA ")
    #else
    #define FILE_DESC1  // blank on purpose 
    #endif

    #ifdef _DEBUG
    #define FILE_DESC2   _T("Debug Version ")
    #else
    #define FILE_DESC2   _T("Release Version ") // this is greyed out in the ide when building
    #endif

    #define FILE_DESC   FILE_DESC1 FILE_DESC2


// myapp.rc2
include "version.h"

#ifndef _T
#define _T(x)   x
#endif

VS_VERSION_INFO VERSIONINFO
 FILEVERSION PROD_VER_MJR,PROD_VER_MIN,PROD_VER_UPD,JOBUILDER_BUILD
 PRODUCTVERSION PROD_VER_MJR,PROD_VER_MIN
 FILEFLAGSMASK 0x3fL
#ifdef _DEBUG
 FILEFLAGS 0x1L
#else
 FILEFLAGS 0x0L
#endif
 FILEOS 0x4L
 FILETYPE 0x1L
 FILESUBTYPE 0x0L
BEGIN
    BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        BLOCK "040904e4"
        BEGIN
            VALUE "CompanyName", COMPANY_NAME
            VALUE "FileDescription", FILE_DESC
            VALUE "FileVersion", JOBBUI_VERSION
            VALUE "InternalName", "MyApp.exe" 
            VALUE "LegalCopyright", COPYRIGHT
            VALUE "OriginalFilename", "MyApp.exe"
            VALUE "ProductName", PRODUCT_NAME
            VALUE "ProductVersion", PRODUCT_VERSION
            VALUE "Comments",  COMMENTS
        END
    END
    BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        VALUE "Translation", 0x409, 1252
    END
END
```

However when the exe is built in the debug output directory the file description always incorrectly says "BETA Release Version" instead of "BETA Debug Version" Yet the IDE indicates that    "#define FILE_DESC2   _T("Debug Version ")" would be used.  Why might this be?  I have used these files on another project and they work correctly.

Thank You...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed:  on the debug build I added _DEBUG to:-

Project Properties> Resources > Preprocessor Definitions. And its now working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to "debug" preprocessor issues like this is to stick a #error directive at the point where you think your macro is actually getting #define'd

Once you know which path the preprocessor actually took, you can try to figure out why it did so...

Edit: Besides the preprocessor run for the resource compiler may differ from the one for the compiler with respect to what macros are predefined.

Comment: You edit: is Correct.  I added the #error directive as you suggested and then got this error "fatal error RC1116: RC terminating after preprocessor errors" Looks like the resource compiler is having a problem with #error (maybe not known/supported) and my original #defines.  Any way around this I wonder? the sam code 'appears' to be working on another VS2008 project.